# Populate Meta tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the data value in the meta tag below

```
<meta data-my-id="home">
```

So far i tried this, but this is actually returning the html.

```
$("meta[data-my-id]");
```

Would someone be able to help me with it?

Comment: It's returning a jQuery object. `$("meta").data("my-id");` should return `"home"` but if you have mutliples, you'll get a nodelist back

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) you can get the element with a certain attribute then get it's value using [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data) method.

```
$("meta[data-my-id]").data('my-id');
```

or use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr) method

```
$("meta[data-my-id]").attr('data-my-id');
```

Comment: `$("meta[data-my-id]")` is just a selector which will return the element, not the `data-*` properties associated with the element..

Comment: @Rayon from that we can get the value using `.data('my-id');`

Comment: Yeah.. I wanted you to make those changes in your answer... ;)

Comment: @JohnP. : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

`$("meta[data-my-id]");` is a selector that will select meta tag that have `data-my-id` attribute, you have to use jQuery **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)** of **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** to get attribute value :

```
$("meta[data-my-id]").data("my-id");
//Or
$("meta[data-my-id]").prop("data-my-id");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: please check the second one................ you can use `prop` method and get `dataset` property.... from that object you need to get the desired

Comment: which one _2. if there is a meta tag before the element without the attribute then it won't work._ ?

Comment: `$("meta[data-my-id]").prop("data-my-id");` this one will fail